# Validation Error whet trying to change ip on Elastix

Tags: elastix

Whenever I try to change the IP address of my Elastix (4.0 beta 1 box) through the web admin interface, I get the following error:

```
Validation Error
The following fields contain errors:
Device
```

(I'm trying to switch from DHCP to Static and assign IP 10.0.0.101/255.255.255.0)

I've done `yum install nmtui` and with `nmtui` I can change it but I would like to know *why* the Elastix's web admin interface is failing with this validation error.

Any idea?

Comment: why not try there http://forum.elastix.org/viewforum.php?f=3&sid=c1fd81e50c5122c1d0c8010022148980 ?

Comment: @froggiz I've tried to register on Elastix forum but they have very strict policies and they are blocking the registration process if the ip originating the registration request come from a spam blacklisted one. I've tried registering from several location: home office, customer: each registration  request was blocked due to that policy